# SQL Join on 2 tables to get all columns

Tags: sql

TableA contains

```
cola1    | cola2   | cola3 | colAB
-----------------------------------
 a1          a2        a3      1
 a11         a22       a33     1
```

TableB contains

```
 colb1    | colb2   | colb3 | colAB
 -----------------------------------
 b1          b2        b3       1
 b11         b22       b33      1
```

I want result like this:

```
cola1    | cola2   | cola3 | colb1 | colb2 | colb3 | colAB
----------------------------------------------------------
  a1         a2        a3     b1      b2      b3       1
  a11        a22       a33    b11     b22     b33      1
```

How to get this?

Thanks

Comment: Are your values of colAB correct?

Comment: Which database? Is the row order somehow defined as you are identifying first an second rows.

Comment: This question could really benefit from some additional details; What does ColAB represent for each table?  Are these values shared between both tables, so that they can be joined?  What database technology are you using?  There could be a number of ways to potentially approach answering this question, but without more details, it is hard to give any sufficient answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [fields you want]
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableA.colAB=TableB.colAB;
```

read on  [SQL JOIN](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/join)

Comment: Only use explicit joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cola1, cola2, cola3, colb1, colb2, colb3, a.colAB
from TableA a 
inner join TableB b on a.colAB = b.colAB
```

EDIT: this is not correct: this will result in four rows also, per the comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you need to find out how these two tables are related as at first glance they are not. This is a business requirements question not a syntax question. You need to understand the meaning of the data before you can query it. It looks as if it is possible that the relationship is that you need to remove the first character from col1 in both tables and join on that. BUt that coudl be a superficial guess based on a very limited set of data provided. YOu need to understand what these field smean and how they should relate to each other.  That means you need to ask the business not us.

If my guess is correct, then you need to fix your data model. It is not effective to have to remove characters to perform a join. If data is supposed to be related, then you must include a foreign key field in one of your tables. This is especially true if these are (or eventually will be) large tables.

You can transform your data by creating a calculated field if indeed you need to strip off the leading characters.  In this case, you need to be very sure, that there are always leading characters and what you need to do if there are ones that contain more than a single digit character to be stripped. This can get quite complex, but better to do once in creating a new field to join on that every time you query. It is not optional to fix your data model at this point unless this is a one time data transformation that will never happen again.